# Xcode11 does not appear authentication window when cloning

Tags: ios, xcode, git, bitbucket, xcode11

It is strange! I am cloning new project from Bitbucket but it will not connect or something else. I tried `Open Xcode, from the menu, select Source Control -> Clone` and entered .git url on text box and hit Clone and nothing happen. It worked before. After update Xcode it can not. I attached [clip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/35cvpz4m39vcc06/Git.mov?dl=0) for more clearance. Thank you

Comment: its taking some time while preparing clone. wait some minutes. it will directly ask to where you want to save your project.

Comment: I waited upto 2 or 3 mins but nothing happen